# cstheory.SE fellows add me in their Google+ circles

Tags: discussion

In the last couple of days, three cstheory users added me in their Google Plus circles. I don't mind to have these people in my circles, I was just wondering: is there some automatic thing that makes this happens?

Comment: Keep in mind, that just because they added you, it doesn't mean they are in your circles (it just means they are following your public posts).

Comment: Google+? What *is* that? More serious: for networking among researchers, maybe [researchgate.net](http://www.researchgate.net) can be an alternative.

Comment: @Raphael I have actually found G+ extremely useful for networking among computer scientists... I imagine it is more useful than researchgate which seems to be directed (or at least attractive to) big lab science.

Comment: @Raphael: I've found ResearchGate to be surprisingly worthless, even compared to the Google+ "ghost town".

Comment: @JɛﬀE So far, me too, but I think that is because few computer scientists seem to be there yet. I have hopes for the platform once the density increases. Luckily, it does not cost much time to have your profile there and current, waiting for the platform to mature.

Comment: @Raphael: The problem is not the lack of computer scientists, but the surfeit of poor computer scientists.  There's just too much noise to be welcoming or useful.  It's the same reason we keep pushing non-research questions out of TCS.SE.

Comment: @JɛﬀE Sure, it's not useful in the same sense cstheory.SE is. The posts/questions that are posted are mostly useless. It can be used for deliberate communication, though, and for easily maintaining a research-specific profile; RG works very well in that regard.

Comment: @Raphael But deliberate communication = email, and research-specific profile = home page.  What's the point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a circle of cstheory folks and shared it with the people in that circle. That is probably where your additions are coming from. You should be able to see my share of the circle in your stream. I don't plan to share the circle publicly at this time, and if you want to be removed, let me know and I will make sure to never share you in any public circle.

Also, to stackers that want to be added to the cstheory circle, let me know and I will add you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Artem. This explains it :)